# Find Dialog Box Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to create a macro in which opens a separate workbook, opens the find dialog box, and automatically sets search and parameters, then clicks find all.  Can get a macro to open the workbook and the dialog box, however not sure how to set search and parameters with code.

```
Workbooks.Open ("File path.xlsx")

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate

Application.CommandBars("Edit").Controls("Find...").Execute
```

Not sure what to do next.  Want to be able to:
Find what: fill with text
Within: set to workbook
Lookin: set to values
Then select "find all"

Comment: Excel seems to remember the parameters of your last search, so run a 'dummy' search first eg `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find What:="some text", ...` with all the parameters you want to set. Then when you activate the "Find" menu function, it should be populated. 'Fraid I don't know how to actually kick off the 'Find All'.

Comment: Or use an input box to get the string to search for (and presumable the string to replace it with), then do the search in VBA

Comment: Do you want to execute `FindAll` to show the hits to the user or do you want to loop over the hits to do something with it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Controls("Find...") as a Function. The Controls("Find...") is a BuiltInDialog which can be shown with the Execute command.
With

```
Application.Dialogs("xlDialogFormulaFind").Show Arg1,Arg2,...Argn
```

you can prefill the values of the dialog box, and than manually start on the appeared dialog.

An example of exact search of cells content.
Select the range you want to search on the sheet, and start the macro

```
Sub findall()
Dim found() As Object
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
ReDim found(count)
Set found(count) = Selection.Find("searchthis", , , xlWhole)
Do
ReDim Preserve found(count + 1)
Set found(count + 1) = Selection.FindNext(found(count))
count = count + 1
Loop While Not found(count - 1) Is Nothing And found(count).Address <> found(0).Address
ReDim Preserve found(count - 1)
End Sub
```

found() array contains the cells, can be iterated through.